# ffmpeg fails to transcode and give output to stream for -f mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming

I have been using ffmpeg for transcoding for quite some time. 
Recently i have got a requirement where the ffmpeg output needs not be to a file but to stdout , which will be later captured and then sent back to callingurl. 
I have got some prelimenary success with flv and avi , but got failure at mp4 when using -f flag.
here are my codes and need some serious look at the same

this works well with player :

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i cat_dog.mp4 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec copy \
-acodec copy -f mpegts -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -re - 2>&1
```

this cannot be played by  player :

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i cat_dog.mp4 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec copy \
-acodec copy -f MP4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -re - 2>&1
```

Comment: What does "got failure" mean?  Error message?  No error message but unplayable file?

Answer (score 0):

As noted [in the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#MOV_002fMP4_002fISMV), the drawback to using `-movflags` is that it is "less compatible with other applications."

For flv or avi format, the `-movflags` option would be extraneous and ignored, but with mp4 it would take effect and potentially break compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the -movflags side effect for MP4 . by " got failure " i mean the  video is getting trans-coded and piped to stdout. This piped out fails to play in video player , while the -f flv/mpegts flags  works. Also what is the standard way to trans-code MP4 output with moov atom at beginning of the video.

Comment: The standard way is to transcode the entire movie, then move the moov atom to the beginning of the file instead of the end.  The only alternative I know of is making a fragmented MP4 using, e.g., moovflags, but you've seen that that doesn't always work well.  MP4 format doesn't support streaming while transcoding very well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think i need to code a fault correction for mp4 format it  mpegTS. MPEGTS  is natively built for DVB and does not breaks the transcoding and streaming. I hope this combination will take care of the breakage.